# Is it possible to change values of the zephyr-rtos configuration file prj.conf using CMake arguments?

Tags: c, cmake, build, microcontroller, zephyr-rtos

I'm using a nRF-52840 connecting with BLE to a phone. I'm using zephyr nRF Connect SDK v2.4.1.

I give a name to my bluetooth device using the CONFIG_BT_DEVICE_NAME configuration in my prj.conf file. Is it possible to change the value of this configuration in the build command that is generated with the CMakeLists file and the Build Configuration?

Comment: Zephyr is configured using Kconfig files. You can use `make menuconfig` or other methods similar to the Linux kernel configuration to change every option listed here: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/2.7.5/reference/kconfig/index-all.html